# How do I unblock VPN that is blocked by the ISP?

Tags: vpn, blocking, isp

My ISP has blocked VPN access to the Internet that is a mere cruelty and disjustice.

How do I get rid of this VPN block in Windows XP and Internet?

Comment: what kind of vpn client are you using? some like openVPN are configurable so that you can change it to a port that isnt blocked.

Answer (score 8):

Call them and ask nicely

Answer (score 1):

If you have some control over the server that you're trying to connect to, you may be able to run the VPN over port 80 or some other innocent-looking port.  [This web page](http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?p=2221487) has a description of a similar problem and solution.

Comment: you should be able to use the configuration file for the connection and specify the local port for the connection.